# Silverstripe install admin js errors

Tags: silverstripe

For some reason my admin screen just hangs with some javascript errors. I have it installed on xampp on windows 7 ultimate 64bit. What could be causing this? Ill post a screenshot of the errors any help would be nice! p.s. This is my first time installing silverstripe ever so be nice. :)
[image: Errors i'm getting in silverstripe]

Comment: hmmm, have you modified any code? included your own jquery?

Comment: Also, please specify the SilverStripe and Browser version you are using.

Comment: I have not touched a thing this is from a fresh install. Silverstripe version 3.1.5 and chrome 37.0.2054.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of things usually occurs when combined asset files cannot be created. Make sure the web server user has write access to the `assets/` and `assets/_combinedfiles` folders, then go to `your-site.com/admin/pages?flush=1`.

Alternatively, since this is a local install, run in dev mode. There are [instructions](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/debugging#dev-mode) in the documentation on how to set this.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @simon_w, this issue occurs due to the folder permissions: 
In your local environment, in addition to the way via yml config, you can just put the following in _config.php inside mysite folder.

```
Director::set_environment_type("dev");
```

In dev mode, the installation doesnt need to write to assets/_combinedfiles. However, you had better have write permission for assets folder anyway.

So, just increase permissions for assets and directories under it. Uploaded files are also stored there, if not sufficient permission, you can't upload files from the admin panel. Other functionalists may also be affected.

Comment: I actually set up a lamp server on a vm and got it all running fine. Thanks for all the info guys i appreciate it a bunch! I say boo to wamp/xampp setting up a lamp is the way to go.